# React.js custom hook testing using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, ts-jest

I am trying to test a custom hook using the jest function, but I don't know how to do it. can Please help me out with how to write some jest Function test cases for this Custome hook.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

const useOutsideClick = (
 ref: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>,
 callback: () => void,
 enabled = true
): void => {
 const el = ref.current
 useEffect(() => {
   if (!enabled) {
     return
   }

   const handleClick = e => {
     if (el && !el.contains(e.target)) {
       callback()
     }
   }

   document.addEventListener('click', handleClick)

   return () => {
     document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
   }
 }, [callback, el, enabled])
}

export default useOutsideClick
```

Comment: Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't list tags.

Answer (score 0):

load/import the hook into test file and then mock it like this.

```
import useOutsideClick from "../your-file-name";
jest.mock('../your-file-name', () => ({
     useOutsideClick: jest.fn() 
}));
```